# destructuring nested object in javascript (react)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

```
const [book, ...rest] = this.state.details;
console.log(JSON.stringify(book, null, 2));
```

logs:

```
{
  genre: [
    {
      _id: "5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f3",
      name: "Fantasy",
      url: "/catalog/genre/5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f3",
      id: "5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266f3"
    }
  ],
  _id: "5ad0ecfc8c1cff1e849266f7",
  title: "The Wise Man's Fear (The Kingkiller Chronicle, #2)",
  summary:
    "Picking up the tale of Kvothe Kingkiller once again, we follow him into exile, into political intrigue, courtship, adventure, love and magic... and further along the path that has turned Kvothe, the mightiest magician of his age, a legend in his own time, into Kote, the unassuming pub landlord.",
  author: {
    _id: "5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266ee",
    first_name: "Patrick",
    family_name: "Rothfuss",
    date_of_birth: "1973-06-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    name: "Rothfuss, Patrick",
    url: "/catalog/author/5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266ee",
    id: "5ad0ecf98c1cff1e849266ee"
  },
  isbn: "9788401352836",
  url: "/catalog/book/5ad0ecfc8c1cff1e849266f7",
  id: "5ad0ecfc8c1cff1e849266f7"
};
```

I want to render:

```
render() {
  const [book={}, ...rest] = this.state.details;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(book, null, 2));

// console.log(book.title);

 return (
   <div>
     <h2>{book.title}</h2>
     <p>{book.author.name}</p>
   </div>
 );
}
```

getting error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined, if I set book's default value to empty object i am able to get title,
but now i get error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
What's the

here's the default state

```
state = { details: [], loading: true };  

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(this.props.match.url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ details: data, loading: false }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: show the full `render` method

Comment: what is shown when you do `console.log(book.title);`

Comment: Does your array always contain one object? Please share `this.state.details`

Comment: just updated the question!

Comment: title returns undefined

Comment: array contains many objects, but the first one is specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading your comments, the details is an array, and you are doing something wrong, which is trying to access to values that are not defined because of an Async call.

so, when you do:

`const [book, ...rest] = this.state.details;`

you are getting the current [0] object that you have, but since you dont have anything preloaded, you will get and error trying to do `book.title` because `book` is undefined.

`const [book={}, ...rest] = this.state.details;`

basically you are creating a default object if there is nothing (which is the case in the first render), thats why you can see `book.title`(which is undefined, but book isnt) but then doing `book.author.name` will show it as an error, because `book` is defined, but it doesnt have a prop called author, thus `author.name` wont work.

after your async call finishes on the `componentDidMount` it updates the state triggering another render and then you will have the data.
you using your code, while you are loading the data use the `loading` prop on the state that you have, so your render should be like this:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.loading){
        return null;
    }else{
        const [book={}, ...rest] = this.state.details;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(book, null, 2));

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{book.title}</h2>
                <p>{book.author.name}</p>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @d_oram YW, had to fix my bad answer using the fake state. glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from your code and error is that the `details` object in the state is being fetched asynchronously, and so the component tries to render before it has the required data available.

You could return `null` or a loading message while the data is being fetched.

```
render() {
    const [book={}, ...rest] = this.state.details;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(book, null, 2));

    // console.log(book.title);

    if (!book) return null;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{book.title}</h2>
        <p>{book.author.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: you are correct!
I did if (!book.author) return null and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have to init your object (book): 
example

```
 book = {
      genre: [
        {
          _id: null,
          name: null,
          url: null,
          id: null
        }
      ],
      _id: null,
      title: null,
      summary: null,
      author: {
        _id: null,
        first_name: null,
        family_name: null,
        date_of_birth: null,
        name: null,
        url: null,
        id: null
      },
      isbn: null,
      url: null,
      id: null
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is during your first render details = [], then you update the state with valid details which causes the component to rerender.

So this is erroring during the first render

Try this

```
render() {
  const [book={}, ...rest] = this.state.details;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(book, null, 2));

  if (ramda.isEmpty(book)) return null
  // console.log(book.title);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{book.title}</h2>
      <p>{book.author.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

}